# Weird copy constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have two classes: `AbstractMailingDirections` and `DirectionLoad`. Both have a copy constructor as follows:

```
public AbstractMailingDirections(AbstractMailingDirections toCopy) {
    this.message = toCopy.message;
    this.defaultDirection = new DirectionLoad(toCopy.defaultDirection);
    for (final DirectionLoad dls : toCopy.directionLoads) {
        this.directionLoads.add(new DirectionLoad(dls));
    }
}
```

and

```
public DirectionLoad(DirectionLoad toCopy) {
    this.direction = toCopy.direction;
    this.transportationContract = toCopy.transportationContract;
    this.pickUpTime = toCopy.pickUpTime;
    this.acceptanceTime = toCopy.acceptanceTime;
    this.acceptanceLocation = toCopy.acceptanceLocation;
    this.information = toCopy.information;
}
```

Now when I call the `MailingDirections` copy constructor (which is just `super(toCopy)`) I sometimes don't get fields of the `defaultDirection` copied. Or not all of them. And using a Eclipse debugger is even stranger:

[image: Debugger]
here I have clicked on the `AbstractMailingDirections` to be copied. See how `defaultDirection.acceptanceTime` is 17:00 in the `toString` print but shows up `null` in the field listing. If I click the defaultDirection, it's `toString` print will show the `acceptanceTime` field as `null`.

This is driving me nuts. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Are these Hibernate entities (or JPA or similar)? In that case accessing the fields might brake the lazy loading magic & accessing it through getters might fix it.

Comment: Damn. @JensSchauder that just might be it.

Comment: @JensSchauder that was it! Thank you! If you copy your comment to an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these Hibernate entities (or JPA or similar)? In that case accessing the fields might brake the lazy loading magic & accessing it through getters might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a new Object in your copy constructor for acceptanceTime. you only tell the refereence to where it should point to.

Comment: This is mostly the issue; it's hard to tell because the OP's code is incomplete (e.g. we don't know the types of the class attributes), but the copy constructor of `DirectionLoad` is merely producing a shallow copy.

Comment: `acceptanceTime` is LocalTime from Joda so it's immutable and should not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what that code does, reach same objects with different references. You need to copy objects. like instead of

```
this.message = toCopy.message;
```

you should

```
this.message = new String(toCopy.message);
```

Comment: Although you mean the right thing i think your example is bad since Strings are immutable

Comment: I try to make an easy example but you're right it's a bad example.